# Should we merge/synonymise the [fire-pit] and [hearth] tags into the more common [fireplace]?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that we have 3 tags that generally refer to fireplaces:

- [fireplace](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fireplace) has 150 questions, of which they cover both indoor and outdoor fireplaces.
- [fire-pit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fire-pit) only has 2 questions, both of which talking about outdoor fireplaces.
- [hearth](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hearth) has 6 questions, and seems to deal with, well *[hearths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hearth)*, which used to be primarily for cooking but in modern times are more of an aesthetic choice for a type of fireplace, especially in older homes & cottages.

Should we merge these tags together into the more all-encompassing '[fireplace](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fireplace)' tag?

Answer (score 5):

I think they're all slightly different. A *fire pit* is a hole in the ground where you burn things, which is **not** a fireplace.  A *hearth* is part of a fireplace, so maybe it could use the same tag. However, folks might want to ask questions specifically about a hearth, in which case the hearth tag is fitting.

Comment: Of course they're all slightly different, but they share more similarities than differences. Tags should be used to group like content together, and indeed, just based on the question count for each tag it seems the community treats them as one and the same: as a fireplace. Should we instead dig through old questions retagging them to the appropriate tag? Further: Is it *really* worth distinguishing between them? Are experts in hearths not going to know anything about outdoor fireplaces? Are people interested in finding out about fire pits not going to be interested in reading about hearths?

Comment: I think if you're researching fire pits, you don't care at all about fireplaces or hearths. If you're asking a question about hearths, you might not care about fireplaces as a whole, and you certainly don't care about fire pits.

Comment: Again, the way the tags are *currently* used would suggest otherwise. There are currently [15 questions](http://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=hearth+-[hearth]+is%3Aq) that primarily deal with hearths without the `[hearth]` tag. Likewise, there are [11 questions](http://diy.stackexchange.com/search?q=fire+pit+-[fire-pit]+is%3Aq) about fire pits that do not use the appropriate tag. *Both of these groups have more questions separately then the two tags in question **combined***, and most are tagged with fireplace instead.

Comment: Maybe the *fire pit* and *hearth* tags didn't exist when the questions were asked, or the users didn't know how to use tags.

Comment: It's possible :), but I'm inclined to believe that users will use the tags they deem appropriate to their question, and it only takes 300 rep to create tags. The earliest use of *hearth* was Jun 10 2013, there's 5/15 questions asked before that date. Likewise *fire-pit* has 4/11 before Sep 7 2014. That's still a lot of questions asked after these tags were created: 7/11 and 10/15 users chose *not* to use *hearth* or *fire-pit*, opting instead for `fireplace` and other tags. (cont.)

Comment: Wouldn't it therefore be worth redirecting the few that type 'hearth' or 'fire-pit' in the tags to 'fireplace' instead? A synonym doesn't get rid of the tag entirely, it's still searchable, it just redirects to the main topic area. Currently those looking for hearths are better off looking in [fireplace] instead anyway...

Comment: Personally, I don't agree with it.  Give it a few days, and you'll see what others think.  The great thing about SE sites, is that democracy rules.